# Dynamically modify allowed types to an effect

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a notification module (given below) to show snackbar based on incoming actions from other modules. For example '[Product] item added', '[Product] item removed', etc. These actionTypes are dynamically added to NotificationState 'triggers' using an action 'AddTrigger'. Under Notification Effects, I'm subscribing to 'triggers' state and dynamically modifying 'show$' effect by passing updated allowedTypes as parameter to 'ofType' function.

---

**Code**

```
@Injectable()
export class NotificationEffect
{
    @Effect() public show$: Observable<Action>;

    constructor (
        private actions$: Actions,
        private store: Store<NotificationModuleState>,
        private matSnackBar: MatSnackBar
    )
    {
        this.store.select( state => state.notificationState.triggers )
            .subscribe( triggers =>
            {
                this.show$ = this.actions$.ofType( ...triggers )
                    .map( action => this.matSnackBar.open( 'Dynamic notification', 'Ok', { duration: 5000 } ) )
                    .switchMap( snackBar => snackBar.afterDismissed() )
                    .map( closed => new NotificationAction.Closed() );
            } )
    }

}
```